# SSIS Incremental Load Error Handling

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, etl

I have SSIS packages to extract fact tables into the staging tables. I have a control table which contains the last extract date for each table. So, the package extract rows where > control table date. The problem I have is I want to redirect rows with error to an error file in the data flow task of the package. If I do that the package will not fail (so I can't rollback) and some rows might actually go through which if I coninue with the process will ultimately get to my fact table. Now, next time when I run the package if I had updated the control table, I will miss the rows which had erros. If I had not updated the control table with the date, I will re-extract the rows which went through. What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a Row Count Transformation onto the error branch? It sounds like you are using the transaction option in SSIS so put the Data Flow in a sequence container and post Data Flow, evaluate the value of your row count variable. If it's greater than zero, rollback/abort processing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually using a Row count transformation was what I was thinking. However, when using redirect error rows in SSIS you can't use transactions. I guess if I decide to roll back I would need to truncate the staging table so that no records get to my fact table. If I decide to continue with the good records, I would need to make sure I delete from fact table first nex time I run the package so that I don't re-insert those already inserted records.